# Sustituir con una expresión regular usando String.replace()

Tags: java, regex

No consigo reemplazar las comillas de este texto `”THE LAST BLADE”` con Java. No son comillas normales. El texto está en [esta página](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/store/p/%E3%82%A2%E3%82%B1%E3%82%A2%E3%82%ABneoeo-%E5%B9%95%E6%9C%AB%E6%B5%AA%E6%BC%AB-%E6%9C%88%E8%8F%AF%E3%81%AE%E5%89%A3%E5%A3%AB/bv5jpq2d9xzt), en la parte de la descripción:

> #### Descripción
>
> ”THE LAST BLADE” es un juego de lucha lanzado por SNK en 1997, ambientado en el período Edo de Japón con una lista de espadachines únicos para elegir.
>   Temáticamente el juego es similar a la serie "SAMURAI SHODOWN", pero también cuenta con una gran cantidad de sistemas innovadores para diferenciarlo.Uno de estos sistemas es la posibilidad de elegir entre los estilos
>   [Más](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/store/p/%E3%82%A2%E3%82%B1%E3%82%A2%E3%82%ABneoeo-%E5%B9%95%E6%9C%AB%E6%B5%AA%E6%BC%AB-%E6%9C%88%E8%8F%AF%E3%81%AE%E5%89%A3%E5%A3%AB/bv5jpq2d9xzt)

He probado con:

```
.replace("\\”|\\”","&#34;");
```

o

```
.replace("”|”","&#34;");
```

Pero sin ningún éxito.

Comment: Cuando me encuentro con "no són símbolos normales" lo que suelo hacer es ir a donde aparecen (consola, página web), copiar el símbolo en el portapapeles y hacer paste en el código java...

Comment: @SJuan76 El problema es el método utilizado, no el símbolo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto es algo que me pasa todo el tiempo en Java, confundirse con el método [**replace()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)).

El método reemplaza un string literal, no una expresión regular. Simplemente tenías que usar:

```java
descripcion.replace("”","&#34;");
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/MYagn8.

Método:

> ```java
> public String replace( char oldChar,  char newChar )
> ```
>
> ```java
> public String replace( CharSequence target,  CharSequence replacement )
> ```
>
> Devuelve un string que es el resultado de reemplazar todas las ocurrencias
>   del primer parámetro en este string por el segundo parámetro.
>
> Si no se encuentra ninguna ocurrencia en el string, entonces devuelve
>   una referencia al string original. De lo contrario, se devuelve un objeto
>   String que representa la secuencia idéntica a la original, excepto que 
>   cada ocurrencia es reemplazada.
>
> El reemplazo ocurre de izquierda a derecha. Por ejemplo, al reemplazar
>   `"aa"` por `"b"` en el string `"aaa"`, devuelve `"ba"` (y no `"ab"`).

---

Para usar **expresiones regulares**, existen estos dos métodos:

```java
String#replaceAll( String regex,  String replacement )
```

```java
Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str).replaceAll(repl)
```

- Sin embargo, el regex `”|”`, por más que sea válido, es redundante (una comilla derecha, o... una comilla derecha!?).

  Quizás te interese más algo como la siguiente expresión para reemplazar gran parte de [las comillas que existen](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comillas):

  ```java
  final String regex = "[\"'«»‘’‚“”„‹›〈〉《》「」『』﹁﹂﹃﹄]";
  ```

Comment: Gracias, pero la verdad es que lo que me estaba fallando es el usar `.replace()` en vez de `replaceAll()`. No me había dado cuenta. Gracias de todas formas.

Comment: Me pasa también por ejemplo con esta descripción: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/p/baila-latino/c3xnl89hzt9r. La comida que va justo en `“Carolyn` no me la reconoce, la comilla de cierre sí que me la reconoce.

Comment: @JetLagFox Porque se usan **otras** comillas ahí. Es diferente `”` ([\u201D](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm)) de `“` ([\u201C](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm))

Answer (score 0):

Error mío, estaba usando .replace para más de una opción, simplemente tenía que usar .replaceAll():

```
.replaceAll("\\”|\\”","&#34;")
```

Comment: Como te comenté en mi respuesta, ese regex es redundante, y sería lo mismo que `.replaceAll("”","&#34;")`